# Can I edit snapshot in iTunes Connect for Ready for Sale status of app?

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

My app is verified in iTunes Connect and is now in Ready for Sale status but I need to change a snapshot,can I do it for this version or would I have to create a new version?

Comment: No you can't, you need create a new version for change it

Comment: Nope once it has been approved then no changes are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change texts when it's Ready for Sale. Apple needs to review snapshot and icon so you can't change. The only way is to create a new version.

Answer (score 1):

**Ready for Sale** -- you can't do it anything , you need to updated the new version **no changes are allowed from apple** and when it possible if your app is in **Waiting for Review** - you can do it in anything

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. I changed description for my app, when it was in store already. Try it.

Comment: can you tell me the process,coz m not getting edit option anywhere

Comment: i checked for the description,yes description could be changed but not getting edit option for snapshot.

Comment: @niket - description we can modify but other things are not possible

Comment: Also checked. Seems you are right, unfortunately no way to change screenshot. You have to create new ver.